# Contradiction of Cost Values in Neural Net Regression Program

Tags: neural-network, regression, curve-fitting, loss-function

I have the following code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time
start_time=time.time()

class Network:

def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

def feedforward(self, a):
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
    return a

def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta):
    n = len(training_data)
    self.progress_epochs=[]
    for j in range(epochs):
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        mini_batches = [
            training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
            for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
        cost_epoch=self.MSE(training_data)
        self.progress_epochs.append(cost_epoch)

def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
    self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

def backprop(self, x, y):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    # feedforward
    activation = x
    activations = [x] # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
    zs = [] # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
        zs.append(z)
        activation = sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)
    # backward pass
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
        sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
    nabla_b[-1] = delta
    nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
    # Note that the variable l in the loop below is used a little
    # differently to the notation in Chapter 2 of the book.  Here,
    # l = 1 means the last layer of neurons, l = 2 is the
    # second-last layer, and so on.  It's a renumbering of the
    # scheme in the book, used here to take advantage of the fact
    # that Python can use negative indices in lists.
    for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
        z = zs[-l]
        sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
        delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
        nabla_b[-l] = delta
        nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1])
    return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
    return (output_activations-y)
def MSE(self, data):
    cost = 0
    for i in data:
        cost += (i[1]-float(self.feedforward(i[0]))*maximum)**2
    return cost
def sigmoid(z):
return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))

def g(x):
return np.sin(np.pi*x/5) + np.sqrt(x)

def f(x):
return g(x) + np.random.normal(g(x), g(x)/10)


num_epochs = 300
learning_rate = 1
training_bounds = [1, 15]
num_training_samples = 40
poly_degree = 5

training_data = [(i, f(i)) for i in np.linspace(training_bounds[0],                     
training_bounds[1], num_training_samples)]
training_data_x = [i[0] for i in training_data]
training_data_y = [i[1] for i in training_data]

maximum=max([i[1] for i in training_data])
training_data_scaled = [(i[0], i[1]/maximum) for i in training_data]

net=Network([1, 5, 1])
net.SGD(training_data_scaled, num_epochs, 1, learning_rate)

poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(training_data_x, training_data_y, poly_degree))

x=np.linspace(training_bounds[0], training_bounds[1], 100)

actual_y=f(x)
predicted_y=[float(net.feedforward(i)*maximum) for i in x]
plt.plot(x, predicted_y)
plt.plot(x, poly(x))
plt.plot(x, actual_y)
print(net.MSE(training_data))
plt.show()
epochs=[i for i in range(1, num_epochs+1)]
print(net.progress_epochs)
plt.plot(epochs, net.progress_epochs)
plt.show()
input()
```

This is for a program that trains a neural net to model a function g(x) given data points evaluated on the curve of the function. A random error is added to the data points as well to simulate experimental results. The program also compares the ANN model to standard polynomial regression (done through numpy).
My first problem is that when I run this program I am getting different values for the cost (MSE is mean squared error)

At the end I tell the program to print the error of the net (`print(net.MSE(training_data))`) and I also tell it to print an array of the errors for each epoch the net went through. The last error on that array does not match the error printed

You can also see this on the epoch graph. The y values are in the thousands while the printed value is much less

My second problem is that the cost does not seem to be decreasing in the epoch vs cost graph. The cost for epoch 1 is roughly the cost for epoch 300.

If someone could give some suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Your learning rate is too big, usually we use 0.01 or even smaller. 1 is super big in comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I tried smaller numbers and the oscillations were less. However, it becomes very slow (I'm trying to make a regression program with ANNs so it needs to be pretty fast). I think I'll keep 1 or maybe even use a higher learning rate. 6.5 works pretty well I've observed.